# Can I get the image height from jquery prior to displaying it?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm loading around 50 images from json data returned from PHP.  To avoid the extra call of PHP getting the image size I'd like to do this on the client side.  Is this possible?

Here's my current jquery call to build the image list:

```
// Create HTML for the images.
var html = '';

$.each(data.profiles, function() {

    // Can I determine the img height or do I need to wait until the image is loaded?

    html += '<a href="/view_profile.php?id='+this.user_id+'">';
    html += '<img src="'+this.file_name+'" width="200" height="" style="border:0;">';
    html += '</a><br>';

});
```

Comment: Are you asking about file size or dimensions?

Comment: dimensions, All the image widths are 200 pixels but the heights vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the load event of the image and get it when the client loads the image like this:

```
$.each(data.profiles, function() {

    // Can I determine the img height or do I need to wait until the image is loaded?

    html += '<a href="/view_profile.php?id='+this.user_id+'">';

    var image = new Image();  
    image.src = this.file_name;
    image.onload = function() {
        var height = image.height;
    };

    var img = $("<img/>").css('border', 0).prop('src', image.src);
    html += img.wrap('<div></div>').html();
    html += '</a><br>';
});
```

Comment: this seems like a logical solution but no images are loaded when I try it. An alert shows height of '0' alert("HEIGHT: " + height);

Comment: @Paul .. I updated my answer, it creates an `Image` `object` and binds to `onload`. This should work. I have this in existing code as we speak.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  Just curious, why do you wrap the img tag in a div element?

Comment: @Paul. The reason why I wrap it in a `<div>` is due to the `html()` function, it returns the `innerHTML` of the current `object`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
<img alt="photo-current" src="images/galleries/1/photo_1.jpg" id="photo-current"/>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#photo-current").load(function() {
            var imageHeight = $(this).height();
            alert("image height " + imageHeight );
      });
});
</script>
```